# ClickOnce WPF application deployment and Installation through HTTP url

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

Previously we use `UNC` path in that case.

We getting file path in our user install dialog box
as `\\server\foldername\subfolder\file`

[image]

Later we changed to HTTP path as `http://server/foldername/subfolder/file`

But in user install dialog box we are not getting complete path except server name like `server`
[image]

Now my question is there any chance of providing complete installation URL path on our dialog box while installing through HTTP URL ? if so, how?

**NOTE** : *Our application deployment, Installation very thing going on our way (no issues)*.

Comment: I have an Example [here](https://github.com/lightlike/DSACharacterSheet/blob/master/DSACharacterSheet/DSACharacterSheet.csproj). Maybe that helps.

Comment: @lightlike Which url allowing you make it?

Comment: complete `InstallUrl`  appearing in your dialog box?

Comment: `<PublishUrl>\\server\foldername\subfolder\file</PublishUrl>` should already be there and then you need an URL from witch you can get the raw files.
 An Example would be:
 `<InstallUrl>http:\\server\foldername\subfolder\file</InstallUrl>` from which you can get to the files by adding the filenames at the end (.../files/program.application).

Comment: yes, I understood that the way it works. Our application deploys and install , working fine but the thing is `http:\\server\foldername\subfolder\file` not appearing on our dialog-box it takes only `server` which is after `http:\\` while displaying.

Comment: Who uses backslash on http urls? Also, do you serve the http website using IIS or what?

Comment: @grek40 `http://server/foldername/subfolder/file` only mistaken , will update the question

Comment: @grek40 updated and only part that bothering me is how dialog box consuming this `url path` to take only the `server` part while displaying

Comment: I just checked it with my own ClickOnce project (also a http deployment) and I don't see the path following the server name either... so at least it's not a special mis-configuration at your side. I don't know whether there is a way to force the information into ClickOnce

Comment: @grek40 yea, but while I'm installing google-chrome  I get to see `https://google-something` on Install dialog box but the template of that dialog box is different of-course.